# Calling SOAP Web-Services with PHP cURL (moving from SOAPUI)

Tags: php, web-services, soap, curl, soapui

I am not sure if this is the right place for it, but I am hoping a few of you are familiar with PHP cURL as well as SOAPUI.

I have managed to successfully submit a web services request using SOAPUI, but have had no luck using php. PHP is currently timing out at 30 seconds (I also tried raising the timeout to 3mins). The SOAPUI request takes about 3 seconds to finish.

If any of you could spot where I went wrong, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

---

Below are my properties for SOAPUI - endpoint is https://ccws-services.ecollege.com/EnterpriseServices/v2.1/EnterpriseCourse.svc:
[image]
SOAPUI Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:eclg:coursecopy:enterprisecourse" xmlns:v2="http://CCWS-Services.eCollege.com/EnterpriseServices/Types/v2.1/">

<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<wsa:Action>urn:eclg:coursecopy:enterprisecourse:createcoursesection:request</wsa:Action>
<wsa:To>http://ccws-services.ecollege.com/EnterpriseServices/v2.1/EnterpriseCourse.svc</wsa:To>
</soap:Header>

<soap:Body>
     <urn:CreateCourseSection>
 <urn:createCourseSection>
***REMOVED****
 </urn:createCourseSection>
</urn:CreateCourseSection>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

I took the RawRequest from SOAPUI and used it as the XML payload for PHP ($post_string).

Here is my PHP code -I suspect the error comes from the SOAPAction, which I retrieved from SOAPUI's Operation Properties:

```
define('XML_POST_URL', 'https://ccws-services.ecollege.com/EnterpriseServices/v2.1/EnterpriseCourse.svc');

         $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string),
        'Accept: text/xml',
                'Cache-Control: no-cache',
                'Pragma: no-cache',
        'SOAPAction: urn:eclg:coursecopy:enterprisecourse:createcoursesection:request'
         );

    /**
     * Initialize handle and set options
     */

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    /**
     * Execute the request and also time the transaction
     */

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: better try soapclient

Comment: can you post the WSDL?

Comment: @Swapn14 I tried Soapclient but I am also having no luck. They do not provide a wsdl to link to, only the .svc

Comment: @Halfwarr http://code.pearson.com/sites/default/files/EnterpriseCourseService_v2.1.zip

Comment: @rawrzors so are you using a username and password in the request properties?

Comment: @Halfwarr Yes I am. I am using a username token that looks like the following: <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasisopen.
org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>UserName</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-usernametoken-
profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
<wsu:Created>2012-04-12T19:56:24.057Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>

Comment: I am pretty sure authentication is not the issue. I have used web-services before from this vendor. However, I that case, they had an endpoint with a ?wsdl. I am 99.9% sure that my XML payload is correct, just having trouble configuring cURL to work.

Comment: @rawrzors i think this is http://ccws-services.ecollege.com/EnterpriseServices/v2.1/EnterpriseCourse.svc?wsdl link you must try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. This is what I used when I wound up using cURL in .php for a SOAP Web-Service.

```
$envelope = '<soap:Envelope> .... </soap:Envelope>';

$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://ccws-services.ecollege.com/EnterpriseServices/v2.1/EnterpriseCourse.svc" );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );            
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $envelope); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml","SOAPAction: \"/soap/action/query\"", "Content-length: ".strlen($envelope))); 

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
```

I do time out trying to connect to it. Try it on your end and see if it works with your username and password.

Comment: I tried your code with the security header added and I did not time out. However, I am not getting a response (bool(false)). At least this is progress! I'll do some more testing tomorrow and keep you updated.